# Erro ao tentar abrir conexão SQL - Server Version - System.InvalidOperationException - Connection is closed

Tags: mvc, asp.net-core, ado.net, sql-server-express

Olá.

Ao tentar abrir uma conexão usando a classe `SqlConnection` da lib `SqlClient` a minha classe `conexao` - anteriormente `null` - fica da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa classe `conexao` é do tipo `SqlConnection` e recebe o retorno da minha função estática `ConexaoBd.GetConexao()`

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;

namespace core.Util
{
    public class ConexaoBd
    {
        public static SqlConnection GetConexao()
        {
            StringBuilder connectionString = new StringBuilder();
            connectionString.Append("Data Source=DESKTOP-IUVDEOS;");
            connectionString.Append(" ");
            connectionString.Append("Initial Catalog=ECommerceGames;");
            connectionString.Append(" ");
            connectionString.Append("Integrated Security=true;");
            return new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

O mais curioso é que eu consigo conectar à minha base via SQL Management Studio e via SQL Server Explorer do Visual Studio normalmente.

Tentei conectar com a string de conexão do SQL Server Explorer usa, mas também não consegui.

Já Tentei as seguintes variações de string de conexão:

> "Data Source=DESKTOP-IUVDEOS; Initial Catalog=ECommerceGames; Integrated Security=true;"
>
> "Data Source=DESKTOP-IUVDEOS; Initial Catalog=ECommerceGames; Integrated Security=**SSPI**;"
>
> "Data Source=DESKTOP-IUVDEOS\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=ECommerceGames; Integrated Security=true;"
>   "Data Source=DESKTOP-IUVDEOS\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=ECommerceGames; Integrated Security=**SSPI**;"
>
> "Data Source=DESKTOP-IUVDEOS,1433; Initial Catalog=ECommerceGames; Integrated Security=true;"
>
> "Data Source=DESKTOP-IUVDEOS,1433; Initial Catalog=ECommerceGames; Integrated Security=**SSPI**;"

Tentei conectar como Firewall desativado também,mas sem sucesso.
O serviço SQL Server está rodando automaticamente.

**Obs:** não há string de conexão no meu `appsettings.json`.

Uso o Visual Studio 2019 com ASP.NET Core 2.2 e o SQL Server 2017 Express v14.1805.4072.1

Agradeço qualquer orientação.

Editado - Acabei de realizar mais testes e nada funcionou.

```
using core.Util;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Testes
{
    public class TesteConexao
    {
        public static void TestarConexao()
        {
            Collection<string> stringsConexao = new Collection<string>();
            stringsConexao.Add("Data Source=DESKTOP-IUVDEOS; Initial Catalog=ECommerceGames; Integrated Security=true;");
            stringsConexao.Add("Server=DESKTOP-IUVDEOS; Database=ECommerceGames;Trusted_Connection=True;");
            stringsConexao.Add("Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
            foreach (var item in stringsConexao)
            {
                SqlConnection conexao = ConexaoBd.GetConexaoTeste(item);
                Console.WriteLine("String de conexão: " + conexao.ConnectionString);
                Console.WriteLine("Estado da conexão: " + conexao.State);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Saída dos testes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou realizando a abertura de conexao e consulta da seguinte forma:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using dominio;
using dominio.Jogo;

namespace core.Impl.Dao.Jogo
{
    public class ProdutoDAO : AbstractDAO
    {
        public ProdutoDAO():base("Produtos", "ProdutoId")
        {
        }

        public override void Salvar(EntidadeDominio entidade)
        {
            Produto produto = (Produto) entidade;
            string cmdTextoProduto;
            string cmdTextoGenero;
            string cmdTextoPais;

            cmdTextoProduto = "INSERT INTO Produtos(Titulo," +
                                                   "Desenvolvedora," +
                                                   "ClassificacaoEtaria," + 
                                                   "DataLancamento," + 
                                                   "TamanhoEmDisco," + 
                                                   "Sinopse," + 
                                                   "RequisitosMinimos," +
                                                   "GrupoPrecificacao," +
                                                   "Status," +
                                                   "DataCadastro" +
                              ") " +
                              "VALUES(@Titulo," +
                                     "@Desenvolvedora" +
                                     "@ClassificacaoEtaria," +
                                     "@DataLancamento," +
                                     "TamanhoEmDisco," +
                                     "@Sinopse," +
                                     "@RequisitosMinimos," +
                                     "@GrupoPrecificacao," +
                                     "@Status," +
                                     "@DataCadastro" +
                              ")";
            SqlCommand comandoProduto = new SqlCommand(cmdTextoProduto);
            comandoProduto.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titulo", produto.Titulo);
            comandoProduto.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Desenvolvedora", produto.Desenvolvedora);
            comandoProduto.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassificacaoEtaria", produto.ClassificacaoEtaria);
            comandoProduto.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataLancamento", produto.DataLancamento);
            comandoProduto.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TamanhoEmDisco", produto.TamanhoEmDisco);
            comandoProduto.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sinopse", produto.Sinopse);
            comandoProduto.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequisitosMinimos", produto.RequisitosMinimos);
            comandoProduto.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GrupoPrecificacao", produto.GrupoPrecificacao);
            comandoProduto.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", produto.Status);
            comandoProduto.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataCadastro", produto.DataCadastro);

            cmdTextoGenero = "INSERT INTO ProdutosGeneros(ProdutoId," +
                                                         "GeneroId," +
                             ") " +
                             "VALUES(@ProdutoId," +
                                    "@GeneroId" +
                             ")";
            SqlCommand comandoGenero = new SqlCommand(cmdTextoGenero);

            cmdTextoPais = "INSERT INTO ProdutosPaises(ProdutoId," +
                                                        "PaisId," +
                           ") " +
                           "VALUES(@ProdutoId," +
                                  "@PaisId" +
                           ")";
            SqlCommand comandoPais = new SqlCommand(cmdTextoPais);

            try
            {
                Conectar();
                BeginTransaction();
                int a = comandoProduto.ExecuteNonQuery();
                foreach (var item in produto.Generos)
                {
                    comandoGenero.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdutoId", produto.Id);
                    comandoGenero.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GeneroId", item);
                    int b = comandoGenero.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                foreach (var item in produto.PaisesProibicao)
                {
                    comandoPais.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdutoId", produto.Id);
                    comandoPais.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pais", item);
                    int c = comandoPais.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                Commit();
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Rollback();
                throw e;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                comandoProduto.Dispose();
                comandoGenero.Dispose();
                comandoPais.Dispose();
                Desconectar();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A classe abaixo possui os métodos de Abrir e fechar conexões e transações:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using core.Util;
using dominio;

namespace core.Impl.Dao
{
    public abstract class AbstractDAO : IDAO
    {
        protected SqlConnection conexao;
        protected string tabela;
        protected string idTabela;
        private DbTransaction transacao;

        public AbstractDAO(SqlConnection conexao, string tabela, string idTabela)
        {
            this.tabela = tabela;
            this.idTabela = idTabela;
            this.conexao = conexao;
        }

        protected AbstractDAO(string tabela, string idTabela)
        {
            this.tabela = tabela;
            this.idTabela = idTabela;
        }

        public virtual void Salvar(EntidadeDominio entidade)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public virtual void Alterar(EntidadeDominio entidade)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public virtual List<EntidadeDominio> Consultar(EntidadeDominio entidade)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Excluir(EntidadeDominio entidade)
        {
            string cmdTexto = "DELETE FROM '" + tabela + "' WHERE ProdutoId = '" + idTabela + "'";
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(cmdTexto);
            try
            {
                Conectar();
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Commit();
            }
            catch (DbException e)
            {
                Rollback();
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                Desconectar();
                comando.Dispose();
            }
        }

        protected void Conectar()
        {
            try
            {
                if (conexao == null)
                    conexao = ConexaoBd.GetConexao();
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }

        protected void Desconectar()
        {
            if (conexao != null)
            {
                conexao.Close();
                conexao.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public void BeginTransaction()
        {
            try
            {
                transacao = conexao.BeginTransaction();   
            }
            catch (DbException e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }

        public void Commit()
        {
            try
            {
                transacao.Commit();
            }
            catch (DbException e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }

        public void Rollback()
        {
            try
            {
                transacao.Rollback();
            }
            catch (DbException e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A ordem de abrir e fechar conexão eu be baseei nesse [vídeo.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4sRHwVoQLo)

Comment: Tente com conexão de string indicando a instância, assim: `"Data Source=.\SQLExpress; Initial Catalog=ECommerceGames; Integrated Security=SSPI;"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

amigo, experimenta substituir seu metodo GetConexao por um mais simples, por exemplo

```
 public static SqlConnection GetConexao(){

    return new 
     SqlConnection("
         Server=DESKTOP-IUVDEOS;Database=ECommerceGames;Trusted_Connection=True;"
     );
    }
```

também recomendo o site https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ para te auxiliar na busca por string de conexão futura.

espero ter ajudado de alguma forma...

[ATUALIZADO]

Após algumas mensagens trocadas, descobri que o problema era a falta do trecho de codigo **Conexao.Open();** no metodo Conectar.

Comment: Não rolou. Ocorreu o mesmo erro.

Comment: estou fazendo um teste aqui tbm, de fato ocorreu o mesmo erro...

Comment: amigo, fiz aqui um mini teste pra fazer a conexão e depois usar essa conexão pra realizar uma query no banco, mesmo com o erro eu consegui realizar uma select e o mesmo me retornou os dados desejados

Comment: segue o link do teste: https://imgur.com/rjYQdIF

Comment: No meu caso é um insert. Verifiquei no banco e ele não persiste nada.
Acabei de incluir uns testes que fiz na pergunta.

Comment: amigo vc tem certeza que esta abrindo a conexão antes de tentar realizar um comando sql? porque eu realizei um insert, no mesmo exemplo que postei com o link, e esta funcionando normal, o erro que dá me parece, pois não fui atrás de pesquisar, ocorre quando vc não abre a conexão, vc apenas instancia uma conexão mas não abre ela...

Comment: realizei uma busca rapida sobre essa exceção, veja no link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282511/how-to-fix-serverversion-threw-an-exception-of-type-system-invalidoperatione   e parece que de fato essa exceção ocorre quando vc não abre a conexão, como eu havia dito no comentário anterior...

Comment: Então eu to abrindo, mas não tenho certeza se é a melhor ordem de abertura. Incluí mais detalhes na pergunta.

Comment: no metodo Conectar,após vc chamar o GetConexao, coloca a seguinte linha: conexao.Open(); *Vai ter que colocar as chaves do if, vê se vai...

Comment: Pô era isso cara. Nossa como eu não vi? 
Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: pois é, vc estava só instanciando uma conexão mas não estava abrindo ela... acontece, fico feliz em ajudar... se puder, escolhe minha resposta como certa pra fechar a pergunta como respondida...abraço